# Convex Hulls in Blender

Tags: modeling, physics

I want to create a cylinder with the purpose of importing it into a physics engine (MuJoCo to be more precise) which uses convex hulls. I created my simplified geometry with 16 faces. Now I want to separate them into individual convex hulls (image of the cylinder below).

[image]

The problem starts when I try to separate them (using the separate selection tool). When I do so, it only separates the edge, not the full face. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Also, I have to give the faces some depth otherwise the inertia cannot be computed. I aimed at doing this either before the separation or after, using the solidify modifier.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate them"? What is "them"? Do you mean separate each face?

Comment: in *Edit Mode* select all faces with `a` then press `Alt`+`M` *> Faces By Edges*. this will split your cylinder into 16 faces (or 18 if you have the 2 caps at top & bottom). then press `p` *> Separate By Loose Parts* which will give you 16 objects. Then you can add a solidify modifier to 1 object and then select all objects and select the solidified object last then go to menu *Object > Link/Transfer Data > Copy Modifiers* so you don't have to individually add solidify modifier to each face

Comment: +1 or better yet, add the solidify, then do *Separate by Loose Parts*, each one should have the modifier already.

Comment: +1 oh yes good point. no more need to copy modifiers that way :)